# TabBarController switch between Views [Switching to thread 12803]

Tags: objective-c, view, tabbarcontroller

I've created an TabBarController with four Navigation Controllers. This functioned well, the application shows by start the first Navigation Controller, how it used to be. 
But after that I created a UITableView (on the Third View Controller), the Application shows by start the Third View Controller for a moment and then it switch to the first view controller. And also the default.png Splash-Screen don't show up anymore.
How can I correct this? The Debugger Console shows the following message:

> [Switching to thread 12803]
>
> [Switching to thread 13571]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem. I think there was some cache saved on the iPhone, so I restored en older Version of the application. After that it functioned well!